# Me da error al momento que cargué el servidor de rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activerecord

El proyecto es de ruby on rails, tiene un crud sencillo pero se realizó desde un computador diferente y fue ingresado a GitHub y al momento de descargarlo en mi ordenador hice "bundle install" todas las gemas que tiene el proyecto fueron instaladas correctamente, cuando ejecute el "rails s" el servidor se ejecutó correctamente, cuando lo abrí en el navegador me aparecio este error:

PD: El proyecto utiliza la gema pg (postgres)

[image: Error de database]

Comment: y tu cadena de conexión está bien escrita? La base de datos está dentro de la misma red?

Comment: No has creado la base de datos; necesitas crear la base de datos y ejecutar las migraciones: `$ rails db:create && rails db:migrate`.

Comment: Lo que dice el error, la base de datos no existe. Prueba a revisar las indicaciones de la [guía de rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database) para mas información de como iniciar y configurar tu bd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es porque no esta creada la base de datos complementarios_development en tú sistema.

Si estas trabajando con postgreSQL, recuerda configurar el acrhivo config/database.yml

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: blog_development
pool: 5
username: blog
password:
```

Recuerda cambiar el usename y el password por el apropiado

Despues ejecutas desde tú consola los comandos:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Reinicias el servidor